# What is the proper way to scale/position static Nodes in SpriteKit so that they appear similar on all devices? (Swift 4, iOS 11.2)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iphone-x

I am not sure how to add Nodes to my scene so that they have the same size and appear on the same position across all devices.

[image]

For example, the back button. This is how I'm setting its position in my scene:

```
class StoreScene: SKScene {
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let backButton = ActionNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "backButtonOrange"))
    backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 * 0.65 * -1, y: self.size.height/2 * 0.85 * -1)
    [..]
  }
}
```

It looks fine on all devices except on the iPhone X on which the scaling seems to be wrong too.
Using @2x and @3x or pdf images does not change anything. My scenes size is set to iPhone 6s Plus with aspectFill as scale mode. Changing the scale mode leads to similar problems.

I have already read Apples Human Interface Guidelines and looked up similar questions but could not find a solution for the problem.

Comment: difficult to understand, too little details. Have you verified the SKView is in the Safe Area?

Comment: @sabi I'm not really using any safe area, just the regular 6s Plus screen size. As KnightOfDragon said below, using a safe area would waste space on the iPhone X and that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your scale is "wrong" is because you are using aspectFill, and the iPhone X has a different aspect ratio than the other iPhones.  (39/18 vs 16x9)  You have at least 2 choices:

1) Set your safe zone in a way that your safe area is 16:9.  Personally I do not like this because you are wasting valuable real estate and these people paid for a phone that goes to the edges.

2) Design your scene size in a way that supports multiple aspect ratios.  Personally I like developing my scene in a square, and overlaying various aspect layer nodes on top of it to ensure that it looks good on all devices.

Comment: Yeah I don't like the first one either. Can you explain your 2nd point in more detail?